# Is there a Stack Exchange site for futurology + scientific speculation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for an information resource and a community of people that have an interest in discussing bleeding-edge technologies, speculating about upcoming advances in technology, and serious discussions about feasibility of wild ideas in science and technology.

The words that come to my mind for describing what I'm picturing is [futurology](https://www.reddit.com/r/Futurology+Futurism+PostEarth+RedditToTheFuture+FutureWorldProblems+FuturePorn+ImaginaryTechnology+Timereddits+RetroFuturism+Automate+TheVenusProject+Cyronics) and [scientific speculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scientific_speculation).

The site I have in mind would have questions and answers that are speculative (to a degree) but with clear (if possible, cited) basis in scientific literature, with the goal of arriving at some description of the bleeding edge and near future of science and technology.

Some kinds questions I'd like to search for or ask (if not existing):

- What is the feasibility of hypersonic flight?
- Why are vacuum trains so challenging?
- What is the current bleeding edge in cancer research?
- What specific milestones would need to be achieved technically for us to consider manned spaceflight to Mars?
- What kinds of laws govern extraterrestrial property ownership? Are there precedents?

There are some communities in the Stack Exchange network that have a few questions which venture into this arena. These include https://scifi.stackexchange.com/, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/, and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/.

However, I'm not really finding these to be a great fit for what I'm looking for. So, my question is: **Is there a Stack Exchange site (or beta site) for futurology + scientific speculation?**

*NOTE: I'm not sure if I'm using either term correctly. I'm just hoping that my description above helps.*

Comment: I don't really know why people are downvoting this, while the answer might really be "no" this is a completely good question to have on meta and one I am glad Mjr asked here instead of just asking in random places everywhere until questions didn't get closed. Thanks for asking, first.

Comment: Speculation: WorldBuilding. Refutation of speculation: Skeptics. Please read the rules of each site, they don't fit the exact pattern you describe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I must first and foremost address what I perceive as a misconception about how the Q&A format of Stack Exchange works.

> I'm looking for an information resource and a community of people that have an interest in discussing bleeding edge technologies, speculating about upcoming advances in technology, and serious discussions about feasibility of wild ideas in science and technology.

Stack Exchange is not a forum. It is not a place for discussion or speculation. It is not the place to go to to have discussions about the feasibility of wild ideas in science and technology.

The tours of many sites have the following text:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. Just questions... and answers.

The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) has:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) reads:

> Thus, questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates, opinions — should be closed as subjective. It seems simple enough: Fact good; opinion and discussion bad. But why?
>
> Most forums and chat rooms have a scale problem. As in, they don’t. The more people that join the discussion, the more noise each of those connections bring. So the forums get progressively noisier and noisier, and suddenly one day … you stop learning.

---

Many of these questions are very temporal in nature. As such, they often become out dated and lead to poor quality answers.

Consider,

> What is the current bleeding edge in cancer research?

If asked on health.SE, you could get one answer today that is correct, and another one tomorrow that makes the one provided today incorrect. And then next week, the first one is correct (new study that bacon is good for you!) and so on. Unfortunately, people providing answers to these questions often provide poor answers:

> Today there was a new study that said bacon provides several benefits. See ariv...

And that's it.  Poor answer.

So while questions about health would be on topic on health.se, temporal questions would likely get closed.

Your questions of

> What is the feasibility of hypersonic flight?
> Why are vacuum trains so challenging?

may be on topic on Engineering.SE, they may not. It depends on how they are worded.  The hypersonic flight would also be something to look at Aviation.SE, though again, it really depends on how it is worded.

> What specific milestones would need to be achieved technically for us to consider manned spaceflight to Mars?

Looks like something made for SpaceExploration.SE.  Again, depending on wording.

> What kinds of laws govern extraterrestrial property ownership? Are there precedents?

Looks like something for Law.SE... and once again, depends on wording.

Crystal ball gazing (unless you are after the type that WorldBuilding does) isn't something that most Stack Exchange sites work well with.

---

Stack Exchange is based on the idea that a group of experts *in one field* will be answering questions on one site. It is necessary to have a sufficiently large number of questions that apply to those experts to maintain their interest in visiting the site and providing answers. If only 1 in 100 questions is applicable to one's field they are less likely to visit the site again to find that other 1 in 100 questions to answer.

Thus, stack exchange sites are for one field. Cooking. Home improvement. English language. Math. Bicycling. And so on.

Having a general "futurology" site would fail because it won't be able to get sufficient experts to visit it regularly and contribute because most of the time the most recent 50 questions will have nothing to do with their field of endeavor.

So no, there is no general catch all site style, and such sites, when posed, get closed on Area 51.

Comment: +1 I do understand that the apparent general-ness of the topic may run an increased risk of non-objective questions and transient answers. But, I really am seeking what you've described here: I don't want "discussion" - I want Q&A!! I'm just not as good at explaining this as you all are. But, I feel that good Q&As on such topics, when properly written, can be objective, useful and elucidatory. I know some sites already exist for a few such questions.. **Can a general site like this exist within the scope of Q&A? If so, does one such site exist?** Please update your answer accordingly. Thx!

Comment: CLARIFICATION: I don't want "Cystal ball gazing". I want answerable questions that address research which is (admittedly) transient and leading edge. However, the objectiveness of the evidence and repeatablility of the research is not transient. This is quite dissimilar to World Building. **Are you asserting that Stack Exchange sites do NOT work well with subject matter that is intrinsically transient (e.g. JavaScript? PHP? NodeJS?)? Or just that no comprehensive such SE sites exist for this particular topic?**

Comment: A site for "futurology" probably wouldn't do well because it simply has too broad of a scope. As pointed out by Michael, your questions cover many different topics that *could* go on our existing sites if they found them on-topic. A site should be dedicated to a specific topic or field of expertise, not a general idea that covers many such topics. The only reason you wouldn't be able to ask these questions on an existing site is because they don't consider them to be on-topic there because of their subjective nature.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that you took the time to clarify why generality is inherently problematic.